# Graphlab: How to avoid manually duplicating functions that has only a different string variable?

Tags: sentiment-analysis, text-analysis, graphlab

I imported my dataset with SFrame:

```
products = graphlab.SFrame('amazon_baby.gl')
products['word_count'] = graphlab.text_analytics.count_words(products['review'])
```

I would like to do sentiment analysis on a set of words shown below:

```
selected_words = ['awesome', 'great', 'fantastic', 'amazing', 'love', 'horrible', 'bad', 'terrible', 'awful', 'wow', 'hate']
```

Then I would like to create a new column for each of the selected words in the products matrix and the entry is the number of times such word occurs, so I created a function for the word "awesome":

```
def awesome_count(word_count):
    if 'awesome' in product:
        return product['awesome']
    else:
        return 0;

products['awesome'] = products['word_count'].apply(awesome_count)
```

so far so good, but I need to manually create other functions for each of the selected words in this way, e.g., great_count, etc. How to avoid this manual effort and write cleaner code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually find out an easier way do do this:

```
def wordCount_select(wc,selectedWord):
    if selectedWord in wc:
        return wc[selectedWord]
    else:
        return 0    


for word in selected_words:
    products[word] = products['word_count'].apply(lambda wc: wordCount_select(wc, word))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `SFrame.unpack` command should do the trick. In fact, the `limit` parameter will accept your list of selected words and keep only these results, so that part is greatly simplified.

I don't know precisely what's in your reviews data, so I made a toy example:

```py
# Create the data and convert to bag-of-words.
import graphlab
products = graphlab.SFrame({'review':['this book is awesome',
                                      'I hate this book']})

products['word_count'] = \
    graphlab.text_analytics.count_words(products['review'])

# Unpack the bag-of-words into separate columns.
selected_words = ['awesome', 'hate']
products2 = products.unpack('word_count', limit=selected_words)


# Fill in zeros for the missing values.
for word in selected_words:
    col_name = 'word_count.{}'.format(word)
    products2[col_name] = products2[col_name].fillna(value=0)
```

I also can't help but point out that GraphLab Create does have [its own sentiment analysis toolkit](https://dato.com/products/create/docs/graphlab.toolkits.sentiment_analysis.html), which could be worth checking out.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I spend a bit time and find an easier way with apply and lamda.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Are you looking for an answer that does uses`apply`, instead of `unpack`?

Comment: I feel that using apply looks cleaner than using "unpack", "format" and "fillna" method. Feel free to throw in different opinions.

Comment: It's worth timing. My hunch is that `unpack` will be much faster than using `apply` for each word separately.